# dynamically adjust frame rate for a paperjs animation

Tags: javascript, animation, paperjs

I'ma trying to dynamically adjust frame rate for a paperjs animation

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="zacCanvas">
    var count = 0;
    var frames = 10;

    function onFrame(event) {
        count++;
        if ( count % frames === 0 ) {
        }
    }
</script>
```

somewhere else I have a select control:

```
<select id="frameRate" onchange="setFrameRate();">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="0.5">1/2</option>
</select>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setFrameRate();
    });

    function setFrameRate() {
        frames = 60 / $('#frameRate').val();
    }
</script>
```

But I just can't found how to update the `frames` value of the paper scope.

========== one way ==========

is to set the `var frames = 10;` in he global scope.

But is there a way to access the variables of the paper scope from the global scope ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PaperJS directly in JS. That way you can easily share variables: paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly